# run python module using poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a command in my `Makefile` that looks like this

```
run/webserver:
    PYTHONPATH=src venv/bin/python -m api
```

and project structure that looks like this

```
project/
    src/
       api/
            __init__.py
            __main__.py
    tests/
    Makefile
```

I used basic `pip` with `requirements.txt` file, but decided to migrate to poetry.

I updated `Makefile` to this

```
run/webserver:
    poetry shell
    poetry run python -m api
```

And `pyproject.toml` contains this configuration poetry

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "project"
description = "project"
version =  "1.20.0"
homepage = "https://"
repository = "https://"
documentation = "https://"
authors = [""]
packages = [
    { include="src", from="." },
]
```

But when I try to run the command

```
make run/webserver
```

It fails with

```
No module named api
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages argument usually includes the name:

```
packages = [
    { include = "api", from = "src" },
]
```

https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages

Comment: with such package, how to run it?

Comment: You'd probably want to add a "script" entry under the relevant poetry section. [Source](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)

After that it should be as simple as running whatever name you called your script directly. 

F.e. poetry uses it's own package as a binary in the following. 
```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
poetry = 'poetry.console:run'
```
Would